# selecting checkboxes in a popup window using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I have a textbox and a popup window opens on click of this textbox. This popup window contains checkboxes.
I want to click on the above textbox and move the focus to the popup window, select the checkboxes in the popup window and move the focus back to main window.
Image of source code of the popup window is attached in the image tab.

Firefox v33.1
Selenium v2.25

[source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luscr.png)

I tried with the below code but it didnt work:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("FieldView_ctl17_MultiSelect1_InputText")).click();
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
driver.findElements(By.id("checkbox0")).click();
```

Comment: What does 'didnt work' mean? Have you got any exception? which command didnt work?

Comment: Do you mean when you click on element with id `FieldView_ctl17_MultiSelect1_InputText` a new popup window open with checkboxes and you want to select one of these checkbox and close this popup and come back to main window??? Right

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch on open popup window before finding checkbox as below:-

```
//First store parent window to switch back
String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

//Perform the click operation that opens new window
driver.findElement(By.id("FieldView_ctl17_MultiSelect1_InputText")).click();

//Switch to new window opened
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
    if(!winHandle.equals(parentWindow)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
    }
}

//Now find checkbox and click 
driver.findElements(By.id("checkbox0")).click();

//Now close opened popup window 
driver.close();

//Switch back to parent window 
driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow);

//Continue with parent window
```